# htaccess prevent or rewrite for certain alias directory

Tags: .htaccess

my web host seems to have some kind of alias folder on my domain called defaultsite. This isnt a folder inside my ftp, so I would like to edit the htaccess on the root to make any access to defaultsite url redirect to the root of the website or at least rewrite the root content.

any ideas how i can do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the "defaultsite" folder doesn't have an htaccess file, you just need this near above your other rewrite rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^defaultsite/ / [L,R]
```